# JQuery-Select2 - Manipulate the sended http-post data to send the text not the IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, http-post, jquery-select2

for a while I used tagsinput for Bootstrap 3 and it worked ok. Now I changed to select2 and it is quite easy and very good. I've got only two little question and I hope you will help me -- I'm not very sure in dealing with javascript.

prerequisites: select2 is working, using ajax with json-response. select2 used for tags-input.

**1.** When the user sends the form, the new words he entered are sended that way, the words he selected from the ajax-response are sended by their id. What I need is, that all entered and selected words are sent as words (no IDs).

**Where do I need to change that in the script?** 
I tried:

```
results: function (data) {
    return {
        results: data
    };
}
to results: function (data) {
    return {
        results: data.text
    };
}
```

But this broke the search-functionality.

**2.** Second problem may be same. When the user refreshes the form, the new words he entered are shown, but the one he selected from the ajax-request are only displayed by their ID.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#keywords').select2({
        tags: true,
        tokenSeparators: ["\n"],
        createSearchChoice: function (term) {
            return {
                id: term,
                text: term
            };
        },
        ajax: {
            url: "/slipbox/entities/jsonKeywords",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function (term) {
                return {
                    q: term
                };
            },
            results: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: data
                };
            }
        },
        initSelection: function (element, callback) {
            var data = [];

            function splitVal(string, separator) {
                var val, i, l;
                if (string === null || string.length < 1) return [];
                val = string.split(separator);
                for (i = 0, l = val.length; i < l; i = i + 1) val[i] = $.trim(val[i]);
                return val;
            }
            $(splitVal(element.val(), ",")).each(function () {
                data.push({
                    id: this,
                    text: this
                });
            });
            callback(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you a lot and best wishes
Aljoscha

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to our select2:

```
id: function(object) {
        return object.text;
    }
```

I use 3.5.2 version